# Get slide image from Power Point pptx file using Python3

Tags: python-3.x, powerpoint

I can't find any module -I need to get the image of an entire slide from PowerPoint (same as it is visible in Slide show-> From Beginning) in Full Hd resolution or even better in 4k to the variable in Python3. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: i fount this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52424170/print-powerpoint-slide-with-python-pptx?rq=1

Comment: but i can't find any example of achiwing this in win32